# Technology for multiplatform 3D + 2D mobile app

Tags: android, ios, game-development

I have a potential client which needs me to build a mobile application for iOS and Android, it should connect to a JSON REST API and show information in a game-fashion (with cute buttons, a lot of images, background music and not boring/standard forms). The application requires a 3D touchable world, which would act as a menu (although there are other 2D menus in the app).

I thought in Unity (the game engine), but the licensing prices are too high. I have 1 month to build the app, and no previous gamedev experience (I'm mainly a web developer), but I don't think that would be a serious problem (at least with Unity all seemed pretty accessible to me), the main problem might be the 3D touchable world as far as I think.

The project budget is about 2000 USD, license included, I would prefer an open source technology, but this is a personal taste.

Which technology could you recommend me to build this software?

Comment: *I have 1 month to build the app, and no previous gamedev experience (I'm mainly a web developer)*. **And** you have to write for both  iOS and Android. That is not doable in 1 month, forget it. **Really**. It also means that the 2000 USB budget is ridiculously underfunded, unless you live in a 'low income' country where a US dollar is relatively much. Your potential client has unrealistic expectations, and should be told so. A highly experienced developer with both game development (including engine) and iOS/Android experience **may** be able to pull this off in one month.

Comment: I really don't think so... I t's a pretty simple application and I won't require to build any graphic or asset, just the world globe. 1 month looks right to me. By the way, I don't think having no expertice would be a problem. I use to understand code. The idea of working with an engine is precisely not need to have experience with iOS and Android, if that were the point, I would build something different for each platform.

Comment: By the way, I've written some code for Android